# Removing from a text sequences of items from a list

Tags: python, nlp, linguistics

I'm conducting research on code-switching. I have a collection of bilingual Polish text messages with English code-switches (say, corpus A) as well as an English dictionary (also a list, corpus B). I wanted to extract from corpus A all instances of words from corpus B - this way I could see which English words appeared in the bilingual corpus. This is the code I used to create a list of these common words (it's far from elegant, but I'm a novice, so don't be too harsh on me haha):

```
intersection=common.intersection(corpusB)

commonlist=list(intersection)

with open("commonlist.txt","w") as z:

    print(commonlist, file=z)
```

However, I noticed that a large portion of my data is skewed because it contains words that are irrelevant to my research. For example, some text messages had large blocks of English text (e.g. copy-pasted paragraphs of English articles - so not really code-switching but quotations). So I'd like to get rid of all of these large blocks of English text from corpus A.

What I thought I should do was locate and delete any text messages that include, say, five English words in a sequence (these would be my big chunks of English text). In other words, I want to scan corpus A for messages that include four adjacent words from corpus B. How can I go about doing that?

(I also have .csv files of both corpora, might be more useful perhaps?)

Comment: This code is not MCVE [mcve], you need to edit it to add the necessary imports and variable definitions. What is `common.intersection`, is it a package? a variable which is a set? Where is it defined? Show us sample input data. You can `pd.read_csv()` directly from an URL, please show us example corpusB and message A.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest maybe loading the csv files (i.e. using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html)) and converting them into set types. [Sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) only contain unique values too.

```
import pandas as pd

filepath1 = 'file.csv'
filepath2 = 'file2.csv'

df1 = pd.read_csv(filepath1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(filepath2)

set1 = set(df1.values.ravel())
set2 = set(df2.values.ravel())

print(set1.intersection(set2))
```

Output should be the intersection.

Comment: Thanks! But this isn't precisely what I meant. I'm good with finding the intersections, so that's not the issue. I want to remove from one of the corpora all messages (i.e. all lines in the CSV file) that include multiple instances in a row of terms in the intersection set, if that makes sense?

Comment: So the intersection set is fine, it's the next step that's the issue

Comment: @Joanneboron so you want to go through all corpora elements (each element being a string) and remove all instances of the values from the intersecting sets?

Comment: Not quite. I want to remove instances where five or more elements of the intersection are present in a row. So:

In corpus A I have these messages:
1. Poszłam do sklepu i kupiłam /cheese/ i /avocado/
2. Nie ma tu nikogo, /I'm outta here/
3. /Albert Einstein was a German-born theoretical physicist/.

In English dictionary (aka intersection of A and B)
1. cheese
2. avocado
3. I'm
4. outta
5. here
6. Albert
7. Einstein
8. was 
9. a 
10. German-born 
11. theoretical 
12. physicist

So I want to remove message #3 because it contains many items from the intersection in a row.

Comment: @Joanneboron would it be possible to share (partly) the csv files? I think it would be much easier to help with it.

Comment: I'd be so grateful.. is there a DM option on here? I'm new to stack

Comment: @Joanneboron I don't think there is, I started answering questions last week so I am new to this too. Hmu on Discord maybe? Ducu#3152